# Laravel HasOneThrough Relationship

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have the following database schema set up in a Laravel app. I'm only mentioning the important columns for simplicity sake.

**Task**

- job_id

**Job**

- client_id

**User**

- id

Inside the Task model I want to have a relationship method to the users table, which in this case is referred to as the Client (`client_id`) on the intermediate `jobs` table.

In my code I want to able to reference `$task->client();`

I've looked through the docs and found either:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users', 'client_id');
}
```

returns:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobs.user_id'
> in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `jobs`.`client_id` as
> `pivot_client_id`, `jobs`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users`
> inner join `jobs` on `users`.`id` = `jobs`.`user_id` where
> `jobs`.`client_id` = 112 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)"

or

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough('App\User', 'App\Job', 'client_id', 'user_id');
}
```

returns:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'users.user_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*,
> `jobs`.`client_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `users` inner join
> `jobs` on `jobs`.`id` = `users`.`user_id` where `jobs`.`deleted_at` is
> null and `jobs`.`client_id` = 111 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
> limit 1)"

How can I retrieve the `User` model from the `Task` model?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for the working answer:

**Inside your `Task` model class:**

```php
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        User::class, // 'App\User' or 'App\Models\User' in Laravel 8
        Job::class, // 'App\Job' or 'App\Models\Job' in Laravel 8
        'id', // Foreign key on the jobs table...       <--,
        'id', // Foreign key on the users table...         |    <--,
        'job_id', // Local key on the tasks table...    ---'       |
        'client_id' // Local key on the jobs table...           ---'
    );
}
```

The arrows show which column is used to link to the other.

The correct referencing always has me puzzled for a minute, so hope this helps. :)

For reference, see [Has One Through - Key conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through-key-conventions)

**In practice:**

When you run `Task::with(['client'])->first()`, the framework runs 2 SQL queries:

```sql
select * from `tasks`
```

From these result rows it extracts all unique `job_id`s to use in the bindings (`?`) of the second SQL:

```sql
select
    `users`.*,
    `jobs`.`id` as `laravel_through_key`
from `users`
inner join `jobs`
    on `jobs`.`client_id` = `users`.`id`
where `jobs`.`id` in (?, ? ...etc)
```

*Tested with Laravel 8.47.0 using MySQL.*

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough('App\User', 'App\Job', 'id', 'id', 'id', 'client_id');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately returns null

Comment: probably best to use `DB::enableQueryLog();` and `DB::getQueryLog()` then, so you can determine which part of the generated query is wrong.

Comment: I tested my solution for the following: a `Task` belongs to a `Job` which belongs to a `User`